# Update attributes without touching the database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a situation where I have an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, where the relation's objects have some `has_many` associations. There is another piece of code that deletes the database rows associated with this relation that doesn't go through the relation, using `delete_all`. I know what the new state of the relation's associations is even without going to the database so I want to be able to set the object's attributes in this relation manually without touching the database again.

I found [this article](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/5-ways-to-set-attributes-in-activerecord-in-rails-3/) which mentions the `write_attribute` method. This works, but it looks like it has been deprecated, so I'd rather not use. It also mentions `attributes=` as a way of doing this without accessing the database. Is there something that can achieve the effect of `write_attribute` where I won't access the database when modifying a relation's attributes?

Answer (score 2):

assign_attributes

It's like update_attributes, without saving.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for a `has_many` relation, it will still touch the database if I try to set it to something like `[]`.

Comment: You are right. I though you wanted to update a model attribute and not the  related collection itself, but it’s clear in your question.